# Are all relational schemas with partial dependencies not in 3NF?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, computer-science

From Database Management Systems, by Raghu Ramakrishnan, ‎Johannes Gehrk

> Let  `R` be a  relation schema,  `F`  be the set of functional
>   dependencies (FDs) given  to hold over  `R` ,  `X`  be a  subset of the
>   attributes of `R`, and `A` be an attribute of `R`.  `R` is in third
>   normal form if,  for  every FD  `X -> A` in  `F`,  one of the
>   following  statements is  true:
>
> - `A  \in  X`;  that is,  it is  a trivial FD, or
> - `X`  is  a  superkey,  or
> - `A`  is  part of some  key  for  `R`.
>
> Suppose that a  dependency  `X -> A`  causes  a  violation  of 3NF. 
>   There are two  cases:
>
> - `X`  is  a proper subset of some  key `K`. Such a dependency is  called  **a  partial dependency**.
> - `X`  is  not a  proper subset  of  any  key.  Such  a  dependency  is     called  **a  transitive  dependency**,  because  it  means  we 
>     have  a  chain  of dependencies  `K->X-> A`.
>
> [image]

1. Am I correct that  "Figure 19.7 Case 1" and "Figure 19.8 Case 1" are
   not 3NF, while "Figure 19.8 Case 2" is 3NF?
2. Why is there no either "Figure 19.7 Case 2: A in KEY" or "Figure
   19.7 Case 2: A in KEY1" where "KEY1" is different from "KEY"?  Does that case exist?

   Am I correct that

   - If that case can exist, it will be 3NF.
   - If that case can't exist, all relational schemas with partial dependencies are not in 3NF?

Thanks.

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Comment: First you ask whether you got the NFs right but you don't show how you got them. So how does a yes or no tell you whether you understand anything? Then you ask whether you have applied the bullet rules correctly, but you you don't show how you applied them. So how do you expect us to be able to answer? (Rhetorical questions.)

Answer (score 1):

Before answering any questions let me just write down the necessary definitions:

[**Third Normal Form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) : A Relation R is in third normal form if following conditions hold:

> 1.The relation R is in second normal form.
>
> 2.Every non-prime attribute of R is non-transitively dependent on every key of R.

[**Second Normal Form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) : A Relation R is in second normal form if following conditions hold:

> 1.The relation R is in first normal form.
>
> 2.No non-prime attribute is dependent on proper subset of any candidate key.

Now, coming to your questions:

> Am I correct that "Figure 19.7 Case 1" and "Figure 19.8 Case 1" are
>   not 3NF, while "Figure 19.8 Case 2" is 3NF?

Yes you are correct as: "Figure 19.7 Case 1" violates *condition 1* of 3NF definition and "Figure 19.8 Case 1" violates *condition 2* of 3NF defintion and "Figure 19.8 Case 2" violates none.

> Why is there no either "Case 2: A in KEY" or "Case 2: A in KEY1" where
>   "KEY1" is different from "KEY"? If that case can exist, will it be 3NF
>   or not?

Well if you are wondering that why "Figure 19.7" did not have "Case 2", thats because it would not violate any condition of 3NF definition. And the author did not bother to have a different key *KEY1* because the conditions must hold for all *Keys* present, and if violation occurs for any *key*, the relation fails to be in 3NF.

> Are all relational schemas with partial dependencies not in 3NF?

Yes you are correct. The reason they would not be in 3NF because they violate first condition of 3NF definition.

Comment: Thanks. "Figure 19.7 Case 2: A in KEY" or "Figure 19.7 Case 2: A in KEY1" , if exists, is a case of partial dependencies. If all relational schemas with partial dependencies are not in 3NF, does it mean that "Figure 19.7 Case 2: A in KEY" or "Figure 19.7 Case 2: A in KEY1"  doesn't exist?

Comment: @Tim Well if you mean that Both A and X are a part of the key then any of them is no longer a non-prime attribute and hence it does not violate 3NF. But that does not mean its a partial dependency.No its not if both A and X are inside key. Partial dependency X-->Y means  Y depends on proper subset of X.

Comment: Thanks. See my update to my post. I added what it means by partial dependency. Hope that it will make our discussion on the same page.